# Illustrator: how to change selection behavior

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

With the Selection Tool, I would like to be able to select the objects that are completely encapsulated in the selection box, NOT including the objects which bounding box is just intersected by the selection. Is there a way to do it?
Changing "*Show Center*" in Attributes menu does not help to achieve the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I believe there is no way to tweak that. However, I believe there are some scripts that might suit your need.

Long list of people complaining about the lack of the feature [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/320076).

Scroll to the near-end of the thread. there are couple of links.